# Google Container Registry : Prevent a group of users to push reserved tag names

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, registry

I need to restrict some users to push 'latest' or 'master' tags to a shared GCR repository, only automated process like jenkins should be able to push this tags, is that possible?

Is there a way to do this like AWS Iam policies and conditions?

Comment: This is not supported. I recommend that you use separate projects for those developers. They push to their own repository for testing.

Answer (score 3):

I think not but it's an interesting question.

I wondered whether IAM [conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview) could be used but neither Container Registry nor Artifact Registry are [resources](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#resources) that accept conditional bindings.

Container Registry uses Cloud Storage and Cloud Storage **is** a resource type that accepts bindings (albeit only on `buckets`). However, I think tags aren't manifest (no pun intended) at the GCS level.

One way to approach this would be limit container pushes to your automated processes and then add some process (workflow) in which developers can request restricted tags and have these applied only after approval.

Another approach would be to audit changes to the registry.

[Google Artifact Registry (GAR)](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry) is positioned as a "next generation" (eventual replacement?) of GCR. With it, you can have multiple repositories within a project that could be used as a way to provide "free-for-all" and "restricted" repositories. I think (!?) even with GAR, you are unable to limit pushes by tag.

You could submit a feature request on Google's [Issue Tracker for registries](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187156&template=1163179) but, given Google's no new features on GCR, you may be out of luck.